# Javers dependency causing build to fail

Tags: maven, spring-boot, javers

I have added the dependency in our pom.xml file for using javers. As soon as I do that and try to build the project, all instances of JSONObject in my project start coming from **android-json-0.0.2013108.vaadin1-sources.jar** and I start getting this error:

**Error:(1139, 52) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method keySet()
  location: variable jsonObject of type org.json.JSONObject**

Before this, all JSONObject references were using the `org.json.json.20140107.jar` dependency of maven.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the dependency code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-sql</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 2 things: 1. Provide your code here. 2. Format your code and error message

Answer (score 0):

Javers `javers-spring-boot-starter-sql` imports the whole spring boot starter for sql: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.8.RELEASE`. It means a lot of libs which could clash with your dependencies. Try to remove javers from the equaltion. As a first step, add only `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and resolve your conflicts.

Comment: The conflict was occurring because of the `com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1` dependency which was getting added when I added the javers dependency. I have excluded that for now. Will it have any adverse affect?